# asp.net webapplication works fine on local host but not working after publishing onto the server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7

Recently, I have changed all the http static references to https in my asp.net code. application works fine when I debug the code on visual studio, but not working when I deploy onto the server. showing Server Error in '/' Application.

I had a backup of working code and I compared all the folders in the published code before https changes and after https changes. I could see major change happened only in the bin folder apart from static(https) changes. On checking I found that the issue is when I copy the new 'bin' folder from the published code. Application works fine when I keep the old bin folder(before https change in the code) instead of the new bin folder(after https change in the code). Is it ok if I keep the old bin folder in the publish code? why the application goes down when I put the new bin folder? can anyone help?

Comment: It would really help if you posted the detailed server error. Without it it's anyone's guess.

Comment: shows this error on iis----The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Http.WebHost.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: you simply copy 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure dll from old bin folder to server bin folder then it work

Comment: thanks for your help :)